# There is a problem about AsyncStorage in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to out some little cart system in my code then but I'm getting only one value in my cart.

For some reason, it seems like going to be an opening array into an array

```
addCart=()=>{



   var sepet=AsyncStorage.getItem("sepet").then(req=>JSON.parse(req)).then(json=>{

    var sepet=[json];
    sepet.push({isim:this.props.title,fiyat:this.props.fiyat,image:this.props.image});

    AsyncStorage.setItem("sepet",JSON.stringify(sepet));

console.log(sepet)

   });




  }
```

and then ı'm trying

```
    export default class aksiyos extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          ApiTitle: [],
        }
      }


      componentDidMount() {


       var sepet=AsyncStorage.getItem("sepet").then(req=>JSON.parse(req)).then(json=>{

      this.setState({ApiTitle: json });


       });


      }
        render() {
        return (
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
          <ScrollView>{this.state.ApiTitle.map((ids, i)=>

            <Text>{ids.isim}</Text>

    )}
            </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
      }
     }
```

but it only shows the last object which I choose

Also I dont know how to remove that objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving your items as an array, but you're also getting these and putting them inside a new array. Makes sense you only get the last item rendered because this may be the only item that's not inside another array. You can fix this by simply using the spread operator.

```
const sepets = await AsyncStorage.getItem("sepet")
       .then(req=>JSON.parse(req))
       .then(json => {
           const sepet=[...json]; // <-- If we saved an array, makes sense to spread it in a new array. Otherwise we get [[sepet], sepet]"

           sepet.push({
               isim:this.props.title,
               fiyat:this.props.fiyat,
               image:this.props.image
           });

           AsyncStorage.setItem("sepet",JSON.stringify(sepet)); // <-- save the array

           console.log(sepet)

           return sepet;
        });
```

Checkout the `removeItem()` method in the [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#removeitem) to remove items.

Comment: After I use removeItem function I cannot add fresh items in cart. It gives Possible unhandled Promise rejection.

Comment: unhandled Promise rejection means you do not have the `.catch()` in your promise chain, try adding this and logging the error if needed. An alternative to removing your item from the local storage can be to just update it to null or even empty array.